# How do I find out how many objects are in a list

Tags: python

basically what the title says. I want to be able to find out how many objects a list contains. Maybe my Google-fu is failing me or my terminology is wrong.

Comment: Please read some Python tutorial. That's very basic.

Comment: searching with google for "python how many objects in a list" gives a lot of useful results.

Answer (score 6):

[`len(s)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len)

> Return the length (the number of items) of an object. The argument may be a sequence (string, tuple or list) or a mapping (dictionary).

```
>>> l = [1, 2, 3]
>>> len(l)
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the len built-in function:

```
len(someList)
```

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#len

Answer (score 0):

```
 a = ['1', '2', '3']
 print len(a)
```

This wiil print:

```
3
```